# Make a HomeController inherit from a BaseController with attribute session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

The IHttpContextAccessor gives me:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

My `HomeController`:

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    private static IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor;
    private static seiren_devContext context;

    public HomeController() : base(httpContextAccessor,context)
    {

    }
}
```

My `BaseController`:

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected readonly seiren_devContext _context;
    protected readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    protected ISession _session => _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session;

    public BaseController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, seiren_devContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
}
```

How can I make the `HomeController` Class inherit from `BaseController` in a proper way?

Comment: The proper term is inherit or extend (and not heir)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing is setting the `static` (note: static is very bad in this context) variables in `HomeController` so they will always be null. Instead, make the `HomeController` also take the two values as constructor parameters and let the dependency injection system take care of the rest.

```
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public HomeController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, seiren_devContext context)
        : base(httpContextAccessor,context)
    {
    }
}
```

You may also need this line in `ConfigureServices` in your `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to add in ConfigureServices

```
services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Comment: While this might be right, it's not the root cause of the problem the OP is having.